# How do I echo a <a> tag which has an href that is using php echo base_url()

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to produce a `<td>` which also contains an `<a>` link which will redirect to a function in my controller which also echos the id of my data. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php 
    if ($this->session->userdata("username")==$info->U_username) {
        echo '<td><a href="<?php echo base_url()gamestalker/edit_content/<?php echo $info->C_id;?>">EDIT</a></td>';
    }
?>
```

This code produces an error `Disallowed Key characters`. Any help or comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using multiple time <?php

Comment: you're already in PHP (and echo), so there's no need for addtional PHP tags and echo

Comment: You don't need to reopen the php tag: `echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'gamestalker/edit_content/'.$info->C_id;.'">EDIT</a></td>';`

Comment: echo '<td><a href="base_url()gamestalker/edit_content/$info->C_id">EDIT</a></td>';

Comment: having use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have helped you and avoided this question entirely

Answer (score 2):

For concatenating strings PHP has `.` operator.

```
echo '<td><a href="' . base_url() . 'gamestalker/edit_content/' . $info->C_id . '">EDIT</a></td>';
```

Comment: The closing php tag looks false ("?>" after "$info->C_id . '") :)

Comment: @Florian: you're right, I've forgotten to delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the result of `base_url()` to the string you want to output, e.g.:

```
echo '<td><a href="' . base_url() . '/gamestalker/edit_content/' . $info->C_id . '">EDIT</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to concatinate instead to use php multiple time .use like this

```
<?php 
    if ($this->session->userdata("username")==$info->U_username){
        echo "<td><a href='".base_url()."'/gamestalker/edit_content/'".$info->C_id."'>EDIT</a></td>";
    }
?>
```

or don't include html into php tags like this

```
<?php 
    if ($this->session->userdata("username")==$info->U_username){ ?
       <td><a href="<? echo  base_url() ; ?>/gamestalker/edit_content/<? echo $info->C_id ; ?>">EDIT</a></td>
  <?  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need string concatenation. In PHP you use `.` for that.

Also codeigniter's `base_url` can take an argument:

```
<?php 
    if ($this->session->userdata("username")==$info->U_username){
        echo '<td><a href="'.base_url('gamestalker/edit_content/'.$info->C_id).'">EDIT</a></td>';
    }
?>
```